# DFT of binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, summation

I want to compute the DFT of a vector whos entries are binomial coefficients, i.e.

$$(v)_k = \binom{N-1}{k},$$

where $k$ runs from 0 to $N-1$.

I use the DFT matrix

$$F_{k,j} := \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}e^{-\frac{2\pi i k j}{N}}.$$

So I want to compute

$$(Fv)_\ell = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \binom{N-1}{k}e^{-\frac{2\pi i \ell k}{N}}.$$

I don't see how to evaluate this sum. I noticed the symmetry of the binomial coefficients and the elements of the DFT matrix, but I'm not sure how to exploit it.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to apply the binomial formula with well chosen numbers, like $1$ and $\exp(-2\pi i l/N)$.

EDIT:

The binomial formula is this one:
$$(a+b)^m=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}a^k\; b^{m-k}\, .$$

Comment: which formula are you referring to?

Comment: +1 @Pascal: [Binomial formula.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, of course. That was indeed a rather stupid question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Putting $z=\exp(-\frac{2\pi\mathbf i}N)$ you have $e^{-\frac{2\pi\mathbf ilk}N}=z^{kl}=(z^l)^k$, so you get
$$
  (Fv)_l = \frac1{\sqrt N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \binom{N-1}ke^{-\frac{2\pi\mathbf i lk}N}
  = \frac1{\sqrt N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \binom{N-1}k(z^l)^k
  = \frac{(1+z^l)^{N-1}}{\sqrt N}.
$$